# Does Stack Overflow reputation have any value?

Tags: support, reputation

I have a doubt about Stack Overflow reputation. Why do we need this reputation? Is it worth investing my time as a programmer improving my Stack Overflow reputation?

Comment: Ok.. 1. gamification is a factor but people don't necessarily spend time here solely for it. 2. Depends really on whether the company which you apply to gives value to your contribution. 3. SO has its own job portal where it might be of value

Comment: Related: [Will high reputation in Stack Overflow help to get a good job?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/20407/31456).

Comment: `Is it worth investing my time`? Well its a community of volunteer . You only does not provide help you learn also . So its your choice . And Repo is just keep a positive record .  And 1k rep!= .043 Bitcoin its actually 0.00043 .. JK

Answer (score 46, accepted):

It's *not* worth investing your time in SO for reputation. That's not what it's for.

Reputation is what you get for positively contributing to the site, for providing good answers or good questions that produce good answers. If rep is the only reason you can think of to contribute, then perhaps this site is not for you.

Content is what we want. Reputation is *gratitude* for providing good content. When you start doing something just to get gratitude, that suggests the wrong motive.

Comment: I don't know about that last bit. There are more people in this world than there ever were which means there are a great many people trying to find some meaning to their life in a very crowded space in a world where things are becoming more automated by the day. If receiving gratitude gets you out of bed in the morning... who are we to say that motive is wrong especially if it means you're producing good content as a means to that end?

Comment: @Gimby Upvoted your comment as i strongly agree, but still it's off-topic and deserves it's own discussion i believe.

Comment: he is correct. with out giving any thing no one care about SO

Comment: How is @gimby 's comment off topic. Its dead smack on-topic. I don't even like that this question was closed for being off topic. I also dont think it makes since to contibute good content for good content. I wouldn't drive down to the store to the store to spend 20-dollars to buy 20-dollars  (I am in the U.S. so I use the dollar, but same logic applies to the currency used in your country) its a loosing proposition. I use this site because I am 37, a undergrad CS student, and I actually want to get some sort of reputation under my belt. I think that's a common use of S.O. and a practical one.

Comment: @jD3V: "*I actually want to get some sort of reputation under my belt.*" SO reputation is not a legitimate measure of your worth as a programmer that other people will value. There are too many ways to game the system, to "contribute" something that gets people to upvote but is actually of no real value. So if your goal is to make a name for yourself, this is not the site for doing that. It is not "practical" by any reasonable meaning of that term.

Comment: @jD3V: "*I also dont think it makes since to contibute good content for good content.*" Why not? Good content is its own reward.

Answer (score 21):

The most important thing reputation gets you is access to more features of the site, from chat to the dup hammer—all of which are only useful if you already care about SO for its own sake.

That being said, I have had people mention my SO rep, or specific highly-upvoted answers, in job interviews. But I'd be willing to bet that the same amount of time spent putting working on an interesting open source project, or writing a good programming blog, would give you more bang for the buck, if that's what you're really looking for.

And the *real* reason I come to SO is the opportunity to put whatever problem I'm currently frustrated about on the back burner for a few minutes and let my subconscious work on it, by solving someone else's problem. Helping other people, learning new things, contributing to a great Q&A site, those are all secondary. And getting some points that might conceivably be worth something, that isn't even on the radar.

Answer (score 12):

It definitely has a value, I was invited to several job interviews where I got the feedback that my reputation points got them interested.

But if your main motivation for participating on Stackoverflow would be to gain reputation to somehow benefit from it outside of Stackoverflow I'd say: don't do it. Participation should be driven by fun and curiosity. or because of the joy of helping. If this is not driving this I guess there are better and faster way to increase your recognisable reputation, by authoring an interesting open source project, publishing well written blog post and articles, visibility at conferences…